# PostgreSQL silently terminates query on error

Tags: postgresql

Consider a query:

```
SELECT *
FROM unnest(array['1', '100000', '1000', '10000000000', '100', '1']) p
WHERE p::int < 10000
```

that returns:

```
p
1
1000
```

Whereas:

```
SELECT *
FROM unnest(array['1', '100000', '1000', '10000000000', '100', '1']) p
WHERE p::int = 10000
```

Returns:

```
ERROR: pq: value "10000000000" is out of range for type integer
```

It seems that in `<` case, query is processed until `'10000000000'::int` is evaluated. That expression results in an error, which is silently supressed, query execution is terminated, and PostgreSQL returns all results found so far. Whereas in `=` case, error is propagated to the client.

What's the reason for the difference?

```
SELECT version();
PostgreSQL 9.6.24 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 8.3.0-6) 8.3.0, 64-bit
```

Comment: I get the same error either way.

Comment: On Postgres 15, I get the same error for both queries.